# UICollectionView paging breaks after 2^24 pixels

Tags: ios, ipad, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

**The setup**

I have a `UICollectionView` that allows the user to page through pictures, 12 to a page. There are upwards of 200,000 pictures that should all be available in the app. I'm not expecting a user to scroll to page 20,000, so there's function to jump to a certain page.

**The problem**

In landscape orientation, paging breaks down on page 16,385. The collection no longer adjusts to the page boundary. If you go back before page 16,384, you can get it to start working again, but no page past 16,385 works.

My delegate also stops getting `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:` the message when the bug shows up.

**The hypothesis**

Page 16,385 in landscape orientation happens to start at pixel 16,777,216 which happens to be 2^24. I think that there's something in `UICollectionView` or `UIScrollView` that breaks past 2^24.

Is this just an undocumented limit? Am I out of luck?

**The example**

I've uploaded a [project](https://github.com/scompt/uicollectionview_paging_breakdown) that demonstrates the problem. [Here's](https://github.com/scompt/uicollectionview_paging_breakdown/blob/master/collectionbreakdown/SCViewController.m) the relevant view controller. If you shake your iPad or the simulator, you'll be taken to page 16,384, one page before the bug shows up.

**The snark**

If you don't think a user should need to be able to go to page 20,000, **that's cool**. I don't think it's relevant to the question.

Comment: Keep in mind that `CGFloat` is an IEEE 32-bit floating point number, so it only has a 24-bit mantissa. So in the range 2^24 to 2^25, it can only store multiples of 2; it cannot store any odd numbers (like 16,777,217 for example).  This could certainly be related to your problem, since all view-related coordinates and sizes are stored using `CGFloat`.

Comment: @robmayoff That sounds like it could be the culprit. I thought it was something like that, but couldn't find a reference for it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this is an undocumented limitation and would file a Radar bug report, attaching the sample project as evidence. If you are looking for an alternative method, you could try using a `UIPageViewController` with a collection view for each page. You can choose the swiping animation, rather than the default iBooks-esque animation, and replicate your sample project very closely.

Comment: Good idea with the `UIPageViewController`. I'll give it a shot.

Comment: Dont file a bug. The limitation is expected and the limit is high enough. Using collection view/table view/scroll view in this way is just wrong.

Comment: It is not expected. The number is high but that doesn't mean it's okay.

Answer (score 0):

You could just load say 10,000 pages and when the user jumps, load an appropriately different 10,000 pages.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder whether you've tried using multiple sections?  Is the limitation per section or for the entire CV?